# getting error in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, initialization

When I am compiling this code in visual studio 2015 it shows an error as "uninitialized local variable'c' used". but it does compile well in other ides like code blocks. why am I getting this error in visual studio?

```
 #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x = 1, y = 0; 
        while (x > 0)
        {
            char c;
            if (c!= '\n')

            printf("do you want to continue the adder  (y/n)\n");
            scanf_s("%c", &c);

            if (c == 'y')
            {
                int n;
                printf("enter the number\n");
                scanf_s("%i", &n);
                y += n;
            }
            else if (c == 'n')
                printf("the total count is %i\nadder exited\n", y);
            else if (c != 'y' && c != 'n')
                printf("wrong input\n");

        }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are not getting an error: this gives a *warning*. But you might not have the full level of warnings set in other compilers. Please consult the compiler manual: how to enable warnings.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour with every compiler. Just because you don't get any warnings or errors does not mean it is correct. And IDEs don't compile! Compilers compile.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
char c;
if (c!= '\n')
```

for an unitialized local variable, the initial value is indeterminate and using that value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Compiler is very right to warn(<sup>Note</sup>) you.

You can move the definition of `c` outside the loop and initialize it like

```
char c = 0;
```

---

Note: Ideally, compiler is supposed to *warn* you, but then, if you ask the compiler to treat the warnings as errors (which is in general a good practice, most of the time), then it will throw the error.

Comment: I removed the line` if (c!='\n') ` and after compiling the code I am getting this statement "do you want to continue the adder (y/n)" twice in output. What should I change or add to get it only once in the output ?

Comment: @sheethu_cool I'm not very familiar with `scanf_s()` family, but it may be with the trailing newline getting stored in the stdin. Did you try `scanf_s(" %c", &c);`

Comment: yes     `scanf_s()` is storing enter key as input buffer. so I used `fflush(stdin)` in the while loop and got the desired result. thanks for the help

Comment: @sheetal_bharadwaj nopes, not really. fflush(stdin) is technically undefined behavior. There are other methods to clean up the stdin. Just google it (im on mobile right now).

Comment: I am not sure if this process is right but it worked; i added           `scanf_s("%c", &c)` before                                                                        `printf("do you want to continue the adder  (y/n)\n");`
           `scanf_s("%c", &c);`                                                                                          so newline character was read in the first scanf_s() and the second one in which user gives the input overwrites the first scanf_s();

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line containing `if (c != '\n')`. Visual Studio is generating a warning correctly because you are conditionally jumping on an uninitialized value. Judging from the whitespace, this line is a remnant of previous code.

Comment: The variable `c` should be initialized. The if block doesn't need to be removed, though it should be scoped (with `{` and `}`).

Comment: @Frecklefoot - The line is unnecessary and erroneous in the program logic, and `c` doesn't need to be initialized if it is getting assigned by the `scanf` statement. (Which it is)